# Как вызвать функцию-обработчик события mouseenter через 2 сек?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Вешаю событие mouseenter на все li в меню

```
this.settings.topItemMenu.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', _this.mouseenterTopMenu.bind(_this));
})
```

Мне нужно вызывать метод `_this.mouseenterTopMenu.bind(_this)` при наведении через 2 секунды.
Пробую делать так:

```
this.settings.topItemMenu.forEach(li => {
      let myFunc = _this.mouseenterTopMenu.bind(_this);
      li.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        setTimeout(myFunc, 2000)
      });
```

Но появляется ошибка в самом методе:

```
mouseenterTopMenu: function(e) { //здесь e - undefined

  if (this.isMobile()) {
    return;
  }
  const li = e.currentTarget; // cannot read property currentTarget of undefined
  e.preventDefault();

  this.closeMenu();
  this.setTopHover(li);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
this.settings.topItemMenu.forEach(li => {
    let myFunc = _this.mouseenterTopMenu.bind(_this);
    li.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
       setTimeout(myFunc, 2000, e)
    });
});
```

Comment: Есть подвижки, но теперь в самом методе const li = e.currentTarget; Сам curentTarget = null . Поэтому теперь не отрабатывает    this.setTopHover(li);

Comment: А сам `e` чему равен? Можно ли тут обойтись без `bind`? Если да, можно попробовать просто в `setTimeout` передать `_this.mouseenterTopMenu` вместо `myFunc`.

Comment: в e находится mouseEvent, пока что сделал так const li = e.currentTarget || e.target; Так работает как надо. Без bind к сожалению никак